# Gecko vs. Webkit : padding inside inline blocks

Tags: css, webkit, gecko

Here's the fiddle showing my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/7QaXL/1/

In the webkit-based browsers the padding of the `<p>`s seem to push the images up, which is not what I want.

So my questions are:

- What is the correct behavior (according to the specs)?
- How can I get six blocks of the same height, with inside elements with padding, without changing their alignments?

Comment: I don't have a webkit browser to test right now, but did you try to add `vertical-align: bottom;` on your images?  
edit: display: table-cell is great for same height blocks :) Though it'll stretch if blocks are too large (err, I guess. Should be tested with min-width just in case) when inline-block will behave like inline elements and create a second line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I can't replicate your problem. Secondly, I would try using something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://wiki.urbandead.com/images/thumb/6/6a/Img_upld.gif/100px-Img_upld.gif" alt="">
            <figcaption>
                <h6>Title 1</h6>
                <p>Long description 1</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://wiki.urbandead.com/images/thumb/6/6a/Img_upld.gif/100px-Img_upld.gif" alt="">
            <figcaption>
                <h6>Title 2</h6>
                <p>Long description 2</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="http://wiki.urbandead.com/images/thumb/6/6a/Img_upld.gif/100px-Img_upld.gif" alt="">
            <figcaption>
                <h6>Title 3</h6>
                <p>Long description 3</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This makes much more sense semantically as now the details are tied to the relevant images, and this markup will allow you to have greater control over the styling. `figure` and `figcaption` are HTML5 elements, if you need any further help just let me know!

EDIT: Upon further exploration of the issue I have discovered that the issue you are encountering (as far as I can tell) is to do with `display: inline-block;` and its natural behaviour. If you replace that property with `float: left;` and give the unordered list `overflow: hidden;` (or use a clearfix technique) the problem should be resolved.

Comment: Errr, even if it's semantically better it doesn't solve the problem: try adding a padding to the `figcaption`.